# How do I add a progress bar to my EMAIL CLASS

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am trying to send attached files using email class, I have achieved
this no what I need is a progress bar because it takes to long for the
email to send and I need something to tell the user the user that the
email is sending.

```
class Email extends CI_Controller{

public function send(){
    /**
         * Load Email Library
         */
    $this->load->library('email');

    /**
         * Config
         */
    $config = array(
        'useragent' => 'CodeIgniter',
        'mailtype'=>"html",
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'newline' => "\r\n",
        'wordwrap' => true,
    );

    /**
         * Override the config options
         */
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('training@pilz.com', 'Training - Pilz');

    $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));

    $this->email->subject('Pilz Course Material');

    $this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));
    //$data = base_url().'uploads/Steps_for_platform.txt';
    $this->email->attach($this->input->post('documents'));
    $this->email->attach($this->input->post('document2'));
    $this->email->attach($this->input->post('document3'));
    $this->email->attach($this->input->post('document4'));


    if($this->email->send()){

        $data['title'] = 'Downloads';
        $data['DownloadFav'] = '';
        $data['emailAddress'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/confirmemail', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }else{
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }

}
```

Comment: I sorted it out using jQuery

Comment: Can you leave an answer explaining what you did and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a loading wheel gif and displayed none my modal using jQuery